# ListAPIView is returning Page Not Found 404 as error instead of results

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have a django rest framework application and I am want to add a list view for a specific url. When I go to the url and expect a list of results, I get alist of the urls for my project and a 404 message with page not found.

this is the list view i have in views:

```
class UserHasPreferenceView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        filter_id = self.request.query_params.get('filter_id')
        if namespace and path and filter_id:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=filter_id, 
                namespace=namespace,
                path=path)
        elif namespace and path and filter_id is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id,
                namespace=namespace,
                path=path
            )
        elif namespace and path is None and filter_id:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=filter_id,
                namespace=namespace
            )
        elif namespace and path is None and filter_id is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id,
                namespace=namespace
            )
        elif namespace is None and path is None and filter_id:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=filter_id
            )
        elif namespace is None and path is None and filter_id is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(
                person=self.request.user.id
            )
        else:
            return None
        return queryset
```

this is the urls

```
user_has_preference = UserHasPreferenceView.as_view()

path('person/has-preference/<str:namespace>/<str:path>/', user_has_preference,
         name='preferences-path'),
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/has-preference/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way of matching `person/has-preference/<str:namespace>/<str:path>/`to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/has-preference/`, I guess django couldn't as well. This is a problem with the route defination not django rest.

Comment: You can try using this route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/has-preference/path/`